# Reading Usb Python Raspbarry port

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, rfid

I have 2 RFID readers attached on 2 USB ports on my Raspbarry. With the code below I can read in the /dev/hidraw0 the registers of the input reader1 and /dev/hidraw1 the registers of the output reader2, so far so good.

The problem is that when I turn off the raspberry and then turn the USB port that was from the /dev/hidraw0 player back up it becomes / dev / hidraw1 and the one that was /dev/hidraw1 turns out to be /dev/hidraw0. When this happens the system confuses input with output.

I wonder if there is any other way to read on USB and identify which reader I am reading or if there is any way to fix this hidraw. My RFID reader le codes it and sends it to input as if it were a keyboard, there is no connection drive.

```
def ReadRFID(file):
    try:
        fp = open(file,'rb')
        if file == "/dev/hidraw0":
            pinput = True
            poutput = False
        if file == "/dev/hidraw1":
            pinput = False
            poutput = True
    except Exception:
        return

    st = ""
    end_reg = 0
    dado = ""

    while end_reg == 0:
        buffer = fp.read(10)

        for c in buffer:

            if c == 40:
                end_reg = 1

            else:
                if c != 0:
                    if c == 39:
                        c = 29
                    st = st + str(c-29)
```

st is the variable with the read value. If pinput = true I know it's input, if poutput = true I know it's output

Comment: use `udev` to create persistent device names

Comment: Thank you for directing. As I'm new to Linux, I have not been able to do this yet. Can you pass me as an example would be to direct a USB port to a particular hidraw?

Comment: `https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+udev+to+create+persistent+device+names`